# CSS Custom JQuery ui-dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need to add a 2 pixel border around the JQuery ui-dialog.

Could anyone help on what to modify please?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the CSS rule for `.ui-widget-content`:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

The least intrusive way to do this is to add that rule to your site's stylesheet (e.g. don't change the jQuery UI CSS file), and make sure that the jQuery UI CSS file is loaded *first*.

Answer (score 2):

To put a border around the dialog box, but not any other widget type, do this:

```
.ui-widget-content.ui-dialog
{
   border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 'jquery-ui.css' add a border to the dialog style:

```
.ui-dialog {
    position: relative; 
    padding: .2em; 
    width: 300px; 
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. My current code is: .ui-dialog {position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden;}